# How to include project common jar to WAR file using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

I using Maven for creating the EAR file which includes WAR files and jar files in the root directory. I also have commonA.jar and commonB.jar which needs to be packed in root/lib folder. I tried to add as jarModule in EAR configuration but getting the error. How can I add the project specific jars to lib folder in EAR file.
I also tried to create custom jar and include in EAR file, but could not do it. I am new to Maven and need help from experts. I am using the below code in pom.xml in EAR pom file

```
     <jarModule>
      <groupId>common.groupId</groupId>
      <artifactId>CommonA</artifactId>
      <bundleFileName>CommonA.jar</bundleFileName>
      <bundleDir>/lib/</bundleDir>
    </jarModule>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>common.groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You have specified the scope as provided, This means that it is available to the classpath and will not be included in the build. http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Changing the scope includes the jars. Thank you Kenneth.